# DataTable with dropdown Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I need to make dropdown as column in DataTable jQuery it is lookinng like as below right now [image: Datatable now]

And I want it like the below image
[image]

and the code which I use is

```
<table id="example" class="hover row-border dataTable" role="grid" width="100%">
    <thead class="dataTableHeader">
        <tr>
            <th>Days</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "aaData": OrganizationData.OrganizationPreference.ScheduleDaysCol,
        "columns": [
            {"data": "DayName"},
            {"data": "StartDateHour"},
            {"data": "EndDateHour"}

        ],
        "paging": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info": false,
        "filter": false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Another way would be to use the `render` method:

```
        "render": function(d,t,r){
            var $select = $("<select></select>", {
                "id": r[0]+"start",
                "value": d
            });
            $.each(times, function(k,v){
                var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                    "text": v,
                    "value": v
                });
                if(d === v){
                    $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                }
                $select.append($option);
            });
            return $select.prop("outerHTML");
        }
```

Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/kt82jqsf/).

Comment: what is d,t,r in function

Comment: `d,t,r,` are parameters passed to the render function, there is another one called `meta`. In order `d` is the the data in the cell, `t` is the type of data and `r` is the whole row. Check this page for more DataTable goodness: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: "aaData": OrganizationData.OrganizationPreference.ScheduleDaysCol  I have this json object which contains 4 object inside each containing DayName,StartTime,EndTime,the days for the first column i can set easiy like data:DayName but for second and third column how i will going to do i mean StartTime===V over there in render function instead of d===v

Comment: Just like the answer from @Tanmay. The `columns` or `columnDefs` array allows you to process each columns data individually. the `data` key tells DataTables what to put in the relevant cell and the `render` key tells DataTables how to show it. It's really rather clever!

Comment: how to get the row value on change of drop down

Comment: Hey @Sidhartha, perhaps ask in another question? I guess it would depend upon your use case though.

Comment: Super cool! Hope this works for server-side? If not it provides a foundation as a start (assuming it is even possible with server-side).   +1

Comment: @JeffBezos, no reason why it shouldn't as long as the time is in the options... guess it could be adapted to use more precise dropdowns such as hours and minutes...

Comment: cool I will give it a try. I am using it a as a quantity selection for a sample fast food and/or e-commence website.

Comment: ` <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
   var table=  $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        ajax: {
        url: 'server.php',
        type: 'POST',
        },
     columnDefs: [
      {  targets: -2,
         render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return '<button type="submit" class="add_btn btn btn-success btn-md active" data-id="' + meta.row + '"  id=" ' + meta.row + ' " value="add">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> </button>';
         }
      }
    ] `

Comment: ....my datatables https://databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com uses columnDefs not columns and server-side so may have to post a separate topic at some point... will let you know if i do..

Comment: so server-side does work using your template. I might post a separate solution just so I don't lose it in the future (and for others to see).

Comment: How can you return the selected value for retrieving  it within another jquery from a button click?

Comment: I echo the concerns from Sidhartha and @st.ph.n.  Once the selected value changes in one of the dropdown input elements, how does that value percolate back into the DataTable's internal cache of data?

Comment: I was able to figure it out with Javascript, which pulls the new value, and sends it to server side which updates a sql record and reloads the page

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way then for the dropdown setting

```
 "aaData": OrganizationData.OrganizationPreference.ScheduleDaysCol,
                        "columnDefs": [{ "targets": 0,"data": "DayName" },
                            {
                            "targets": 1,
                            "data": "StartDateTime",
                           "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                    var $select = $("<select></select>", {
                                    });
                                    $.each(times, function (k, v) {

                                        var $option = $("<option></option>", {
                                            "text": v,
                                            "value": v
                                        });
                                        if (data === v) {
                                            $option.attr("selected", "selected")
                                        }
                                        $select.append($option);
                                    });
                                    return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

DataTables seem to have an editor for this type of thing as refrenced by Samyukta and others: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

I would say that is the easiest answer. It is however, a commercial extension with a free trial only.

If you wanted some jquery code to simply change the static times to dropdown boxes, you could give this a shot:

```
//utility functions to get half-hour increment lists
function getTimeList(){
    var iterations = 48;
    var result = [];
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
        var hour = Math.floor(i / 2);
        var minute = (i % 2) > 0 ? '30' : '00';
        result.push(hour + ':' + minute);
    }
    return result;
}

function getOptionTimeList(){
    var raw = getTimeList();
    var iterations = raw.length;
    var result = '';
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
        result = result + '<option>' + raw[i] + '</option>';
    }
    return result;
}


//I'm using the not selector to avoid changing the days into dropdown by accident
$('#example tbody tr td:not(#example tbody tr:first-child)').each(
    function(index, element){
        var value = element.innerHTML;
        var optionList = getOptionTimeList();
        var replacement = '<td><select>' + optionList + '</select></td>';


        $(element).replaceWith(replacement)
    }
);
```

This should get you the drop down boxes where you need them. I'll revise this if you have problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this, this is what i'm using now.

https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit

Look at this example:

```
"inputTypes": [
            {
                "column":0, 
                "type":"text", 
                "options":null 
            }, 
            {
                "column":1, 
                "type": "list",
                "options":[
                    { "value": "1", "display": "Beaty" },
                    { "value": "2", "display": "Doe" },
                    { "value": "3", "display": "Dirt" }
                ]
            }
```

Hope it help someone.