# DataTable custom filter dropdown

Tags: jquery, filter, datatable

i have a table with custom filter next to header

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
 <thead bgcolor="#c5c5c5">
 <tr>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>Start</th>
  <th>End</th>
 </tr>
 <tr class="filterrow">
  <th class="select-filter">
    <select class="form-control" placeholder="Type">
      <option value="">Search</option>
    </select>
  </th>
  <th class="clear-filter text-center"></th>
  <th class="clear-filter text-center"></th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

data from my database looks like this

```
    type     |   start    |    end
____________________________________
    orig     |    01      |    05
    classA   |    01      |    05
    classB   |    01      |    05
    classA   |    01      |    05
    classB   |    01      |    05
    orig     |    01      |    05
    orig     |    01      |    05
```

what i wanted to do was to get the data from the datatable then append it to my custom select element
which will get the value of `orig`, classA, `classB` so that my select element would look like this

```
<select class="form-control" placeholder="Type">
  <option value="">Search</option>
  <option value="orig">orig</option>
  <option value="classA">classA</option>
  <option value="classB">classB</option>
</select>
```

this is the script i use

```
$.each($('.select-filter', dataTable.table().header()), function () {
    var column = dataTable.column($(this).index());
    $( 'select', this).on( 'change', function () {
        if ( column.search() !== this.value ) {
            column
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();

        } else if ( column.search() !== "" ) {
            column
                .draw();
        }
    });
});
```

this is how i wanted to look like

[image]

Comment: so you want to select dropdown value by type value ?

Comment: yes i wanted to get the type value on the datatable then append it to my select dropdown

Comment: Maybe this is what you want [DataTable with dropdown Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031483/datatable-with-dropdown-column/36033586)

Comment: its a bit different so i added an image on how i wanted it my table with search filter to look like.

Comment: i tried the script from this [DataTables example - Individual column filtering (select inputs)](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/DataTables-Jquery-Table-Plugin/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Loin Smith Yes ! Because this example loads options value on each column value. But you wish all options from database.